# Is it possible to have per file type key mapping in Vim

Tags: vim, html

I just discovered lately that when you enter a *non breaking space(**nbsp**)* in an HTML document 
and set the `encoding` to utf-8, you wont' have to enter `nbsp;` repeatedly to format text. I at first
thought, hey, why don't I map this to the space bar like so `:imap <SPACE> <C-R>=nr2char(160)<CR>`.
I later edited my `.vimrc` and when I restarted Vim, I got dozen errors about some function needing a
name even though I had given it. I realised that the `nbsp` is not treated as a space(duh) even though it
looks like one. So, I thought a better way would be to have a per file type mapping, so that I when I am editing a html document, the space inserts an `nbsp` and a normal space `chr(32)` when editing any other file.
**How do I do this?**

Comment: If you're having to use that many non-breaking spaces, something else is probably wrong. What's your ultimate goal here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you found a way that makes life simpler, wouldn't go for it. I just want to not have to see nbsps plus I won't have to be forced to use <pre> tags whenever I'm entering code. If it's not possible then fine, I can live without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `au[tocommand]` command takes a `FileType` event that runs when `filetype` has been set (e.g. on startup with a filename). E.g. in `~/.vimrc`:

```
au Filetype python source ~/.vim/scripts/python.vim
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've figured it out. `au BufRead *.html so C:\mine\.vim\map_space.vim.`

Answer (score 4):

You can use filetype plugins which only get sourced when the file is of a certain filetype. To set this up create the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim` and put your commands in this file. If there is already a file you could create a directory called html and then every file in the directory will be sourced. Take a look at [`:h ftplugin-name`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#ftplugin-name) for other naming options. (If the directories do not exist create them)

All that you need to have in your vimrc is `filetype plugin indent on` (indent really isn't necessary for this but normally useful).

It might also be important to make the mapping local to the buffer only by using

```
map <buffer>
```

It might also be useful to look over `:h ftplugin` and `:h filetype`

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff for pointing out the buffer part. The mapping kept affecting even non html files.